# Saving an array of new entities via breeze context "saveChanges"

Tags: breeze

If I have an entity that contains a 1:n collection of another entity then what is the correct way to save the collection?

I've got to this (code not finalised/checked yet):

```
return datacontext.savechanges([parentEntity]).then(function() {
    for (var i=0;i < childArray.length;i++) {

        var newChildEntity;
        return datacontext.makeNewChildEntity(newChildEntity).then(function() {
            newChildEntity.parentID(parentEntity().id());
            ...
            //set other newChildEntity properties
            ...
            return datacontext.savechanges([newChildEntity]).then(function() {               
                 //set finished flag and exit function...
            }

        }
    }
}
```

"datacontext" is an async module with various exposed methods including creating a new childEntity.

Whereas I haven't tested this yet, it kind of logically works for me, but am I right to be looping around in the createEntity/modifyEntity/saveEntity loop for each new child object I want to add to the collection of childEntities?  Is this the only way to do it or is there a way of doing all childEntities in one hit?

The "parentID" is an identity field - store generated so I have to wait for the intitial parent save to finish before I can use the returned ID.

Edited to add: I don't think I need to have a "then" on the end of the async newChildEntity save, do I?  I need it to be async still so it can go off and loop through multiple childEntities quickly as the dependent bit is the id from the parent record that's already generated. All the child records share the same parentID so I can set off multiple saves without waiting for the saveChanges method to respond, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze's EntityManager.saveChanges can save any number of entities in a single call, which is substantially more performant than trying to call saveChanges once per entity.

Also, I'm not sure why your makeNewChildEntity needs to be asynchronous, Breeze's EntityManager.createEntity itself is synchronous, so I think that all you need to do is something like this.

```
return datacontext.savechanges([parentEntity]).then(function() {
    var listOfEntities = [parentEntity];
    for (var i=0;i < childArray.length;i++) {
        // synchronous makeNewChildEntity
        var newChildEntity = datacontext.makeNewChildEntity();
        newChildEntity.parentID(parentEntity().id());
        ...
        //set other newChildEntity properties
        ...
        listOfEntities.push(newChildEntity);
     }
     // alternatively use datacontext.savechanges(listOfEntities).then(...)
     return datacontext.savechanges().then(function() {               
             //set finished flag and exit function...
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Ah yes. Good point on the synchronous nature of "createEntity", I'd forgotten that.  I'll have a quick go at implementing this, but it looks good at a glance, thanks for the guidance Jay.

Comment: Just one thing Jay - what does this line do please? `var listOfEntities = [parentEntity];`? Is this a breeze related function I'm unaware of?

Comment: In case you wanted to create an array containing the parentEntity and its list of children.  This just starts the array containing the parentEntity. (See the alternate call).